# Как сделать триггер,что бы при добавлении записи в таблицу1 создавалась таблица2 с полем из таблицы1

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Есть таблица 'Отделы'.Там хранятся имена и шифры отделов.
Как сделать что-бы при добавлении записи в 'Отделы' создавалась таблица с именем из
'Отделы'.
Например,
'Отделы'-> добавление записи->name=ВТиПО;code=1304000;
Создается таблица 'ВТиПО' а в ней поля:'КОД';'Квалификация'
Спасибо

Comment: Это можно сделать только динамическим SQL. И этого не следует делать ни к воем случае. Вы впоследствии не сможете работать с такими таблицами. Скорее всего вам нужна всего одна таблица с полями Код, Квалификация и ID-отдела из первой таблицы

Comment: Можно и так, но как мне это автоматизировать

Comment: Вам не надо это автоматизировать. Если вы создадите отдельные таблицы для каждого отдела то вы не сможете с ними работать средствами языка SQL, он для этого не предназначен

Comment: Как вы потом будете обращаться к записям таблицы ВТиПО ? В любом SQL запросе имена таблиц должны быть заданы явно, их нельзя брать из переменных или других таблиц. А значит для работы с каждым отделом вам придется писать отдельный код, который работает только с ним и в случае переименования отдела править везде этот код

Comment: Спасибо,я пересмотрел архитектуру бд.